# What does error "request for member 'selectedCountry' in something not a structure or union" mean?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My code is: `dvController.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;`

Why do I get the error "request for member 'selectedCountry' in something not a structure or union"?

Comment: Can you include a larger code snippet that may reveal what's going on?  In particular, the declaration of `dvController`.

Answer (score 12):

You are probably trying to access a property "selectedCountry" on an object, and you forgot to include that header file.  (At least that's what I usually do wrong when I get this error.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `dvController` is a pointer (to a structure) and not the structure.  You need to use '`->`' instead of '`.`', perhaps.

Comment: I can't verify this, but I do not think the -> is used frequently in objective-c, iphone programming.

Comment: Hmmm...now you mention it, I'm not sure either.  However, I know that the GCC (as opposed to the Objective-C compiler) will produce that error when you try to use '.' instead of '->'.

Answer (score 0):

also if the types are NOT the same you can get this message.  Casting to the right type usually resolves this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have encountered this problem when I have a member or variable that hasn't properly been initialized. Check to make sure that each of your objects has memory and is initialized properly.

Also, your question isn't as clear as it could be since there is the local variable selectedCountry and the member. Which one is being referred to here? I would assume the member, if the variable is actually a member of whatever is "self" that might be your problem. Whenever I program, I make sure to make distinctions between locals, members of the current class, and members of other classes so that it's easy to see what's going on when bugs come up. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this issue!

What was doing it in my case, was that I was attempting to access a property on an object of a different type!

It hadn't moaned about alloc'ing and init'ing the object with a different type, but it sure as hell moaned about the property!